# Calculating ALL nested level aggregations of specific Column ( SUM, AVG, STDEV) in dataframe

Tags: python, r, aggregate-functions

I have a table that looks like below (simplified):

```
col_A   col_B   col_C
A       37      2
B       28      7
C       10      5
D       11      5
E       99      4
```

I would like to get a table with all nested combinations of each level of col_A and calculate, say, an average within the subgroup: for example the choose-any-2 table would look like (10 unique level combinations):

```
Grp_2   AVG (col_B/col_C)
A,B     7.76
A,C     6.61
A,D     7.55
…       …
D,E     12.99
```

Choose-any-4 would look like (5 unique level combinations):

```
Grp_4   AVG (col_B/col_C)
A,B,C,D 7.84
A,B,C,E 6.68
A,C,D,E 7.63
…       …
B,C,D,E 13.12
```

(order od preference) *R, SQL(postgres, ANSI) , Python.*;
My current solution (below) in **R** does not scale well as the number of levels of `col_A` grow:

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col_A=c("A", "B","C", "D", "E"), col_B=c(37,28,10,11,99), col_C=c(2,7,5,5,4))

nested_subgroup_agg <- function(choice = 2, mydf = NULL) {
  library(tidyverse)
  dfx <-
    combn(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), choice) %>%
    t() %>%
    as_tibble()
  try(if (choice <= 1) {
    stop("Can't Choose less than 2 levels at a time")
  }
  else{
    if (choice == 2) {
      val <- map_dbl(1:nrow(dfx), function(i) {
        (mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V1[i]] + mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V2[i]]) /
          (mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V1[i]] + mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V2[i]])
      })
    }
    else{
      if (choice == 3) {
        val <- map_dbl(1:nrow(dfx), function(i) {
          (mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V1[i]] + mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V2[i]] + mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V3[i]]) /
            (mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V1[i]] + mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V2[i]] + mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V3[i]])
        })
      }
      else{
        if (choice == 4) {
          val <- map_dbl(1:nrow(dfx), function(i) {
            (mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V1[i]] + mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V2[i]] + mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V3[i]] + mydf$col_B[mydf$col_A == dfx$V4[i]]) /
              (mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V1[i]] + mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V2[i]] + mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V3[i]] + mydf$col_C[mydf$col_A == dfx$V4[i]])
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })
  dfx$val <- val
  dfx
}
## Example
df <-
  tibble(
    col_A = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    col_B = c(37, 28, 10, 11, 99),
    col_C = c(2, 7, 5, 5, 4)
  )
nested_subgroup_agg(choice = 4, mydf = df)
```

Can you help improve?

Comment: I removed the SQL tags because your question is about data frames in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using data.table:

```
nested_subgroup_agg <- function(choice=2, mydf) {
    ans <- setDT(mydf)[.(g=rep(seq(choose(.N, choice)), each=choice), col_A=c(combn(col_A, choice))), on=.(col_A)][, 
        .(toString(col_A), sum(col_B) / sum(col_C)), g]
    setnames(ans, names(ans)[-1L], c(paste0("Grp_", choice), "val"))[]
}

nested_subgroup_agg(3, DT)
```

output:

```
     g   Grp_3       val
 1:  1 A, B, C  5.357143
 2:  2 A, B, D  5.428571
 3:  3 A, B, E 12.615385
 4:  4 A, C, D  4.833333
 5:  5 A, C, E 13.272727
 6:  6 A, D, E 13.363636
 7:  7 B, C, D  2.882353
 8:  8 B, C, E  8.562500
 9:  9 B, D, E  8.625000
10: 10 C, D, E  8.571429
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("col_A   col_B   col_C
A       37      2
B       28      7
C       10      5
D       11      5
E       99      4")
```

Answer (score 2):

An idea is to use `combn` to get all the combination of the rows (considering that you have 1 Letter per row) and then simply aggregate every 2 rows, i.e.

```
#get a df with all combination of rows
new_d <- dd[c(combn(nrow(dd), 2)),]

#Aggregate
#You can use `aggregate` or `lapply(split())`
lapply(split(new_d, rep(seq((nrow(new_d)) / 2), each = 2)), function(i)sum(i$col_C))
```

**DATA**

```
dput(dd)
structure(list(col_A = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), col_B = c(37L, 28L, 10L, 11L, 99L
), col_C = c(2L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```